# Wrap legend title in ggplot (geom_bar / fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar plot that has one very long legend element. I tried to use `str_wrap` but it didn't work. My `x` is not the issue, but rather the `fill` values. Can someone help me? How can I adapt the `str_wrap` to a plot using the fill aesthetics?

Some example data:

```
sex <- c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
profession <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d")
df <- data.frame(sex, profession)
```

My code:

```
ggplot(dat_sexpermedia_journalist,
       mapping = aes(x = profession, fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
  labs(x = "professions",
       y = "count", fill = "sex") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[Issue seen in x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UKc9.png)

Comment: Try with `scale_fill_brewer(..., labels = scales::label_wrap(10))`

Comment: It would help to provide a [good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you @stefan! That worked right away. Is there a possibility in the scale_fill_brewer to align the labels on top/bottom? As for @AndyBrown: Thank you for the advice. I'm still very new to this. I will add a data frame that makes the example easily reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments you could wrap the legend labels via `scale_fill_brewer(..., labels = scales::label_wrap(10))`. The alignment of the labels could be set via the `guide` argument of the scale, e.g. `guide = guide_legend(label.vjust = 1)` will align the labels at the top, while 0 will align at the bottom. Moreover, I added an `override.aes = list(size = 0))`. The reason is that by default a (white) border line is drawn around the legend keys so that the labels do not align perfectly with the keys. To remove the border line I set its size to zero.

```r
library(ggplot2)

sex <- c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1) 
profession <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", rep(paste(rep("World", 5), collapse = ", "), 3))
df <- data.frame(sex, profession)

ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = sex, fill = profession)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens", labels = scales::label_wrap(20), 
                    guide = guide_legend(label.vjust = 1, override.aes = list(size = 0))) +
  labs(x = "Medienformen",
       y = "Anzahl", fill = "Geschlecht") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]